# Finding overlapping Locations in Android

Tags: java, android, graph, location, graph-theory

Now with location services we can get the exact position with latitude and longitude, then we can find the potential area by using accuracy.

My question is let's say we have a list of `Location`s. I have a location(let's say a) that is not in this list of locations and I want to know whether a completely overlaps with the combination of the all Locations within list.

For example the circle with Maroon inside is a, and green unfilled ones are the list of locations

[image: First picture]

[image: Second picture]

The first one should return false but the second one should return true.

I really cannot think of any efficient way to do this. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find out if 'a' overlaps with ANY of those other locations? Or with ALL of them?

Comment: The combination of all of them. For instance in second image it overlaps with 2 of them completely and it should return true for the entire list

Comment: This cannot be an aswer, has to be a comment.

Comment: @Salil, I could not comment it due to the lack of my reputation points